The scene from an imported Reality Composer file does not appear unless an ARReferenceObject is set up manually
I would like to load a .reality file exported from Reality Composer (containing an object anchor and a model) into RealityKit.
As per my current understanding, it should be enough to load the root level AnchorEntity from the .reality file and add it to the scene by calling view.scene.addAnchor() (see // 1: in the code below). This way, however, object detection is not set up correctly, hence the scene does not appear.
If I, however, explicitly add the AR reference object (using the .arobject file used for creating the scene in RealityComposer) to ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.detectionObjects (see // 2. in the code), and then, in a callback for the event when the corresponding object anchor gets added to the scene, manually attach the contents of the scene to this anchor, the scene gets displayed correctly (see // 3. in the code).
Why do I need these extra steps? What am I missing for importing the RealityComposer scene in a way that properly sets up object tracking for the AnchorEntity contained therein?
P.s. for the sake of brevity, I am loading all files synchronously in this example.
Here is the code:
struct RealityKitView: UIViewRepresentable {

    private static let logger = Logger(
        subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!,
        category: String(describing: RealityKitView.self)
    )

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        let view = ARView()

        let session = view.session
        let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

        // 1: Try to load the .reality file (nothing appears in the ARView):
        let realityFileSceneURL = Self.createRealityURL(filename: "ImpactHub_Sign", sceneName: "Scene")
        if let realityFileSceneURL {
            do {
                let anchorEntity = try Entity.loadAnchor(contentsOf: realityFileSceneURL)
                view.scene.addAnchor(anchorEntity)
            } catch {
                debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }

        // 2: Add detection reference objects:
        config.detectionObjects = ARReferenceObject.referenceObjects(inGroupNamed: "AR", bundle: Bundle.main)!

        session.run(config, options: [.resetTracking])

        context.coordinator.view = view
        session.delegate = context.coordinator

        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: ARView, context: Context) {
    }

    static func createRealityURL(filename: String,
                          sceneName:String) -> URL? {
        guard let realityFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: "reality")
 else {
            print("Error finding Reality file \(filename)")
            return nil
        }
        let realityFileSceneURL = realityFileURL.appendingPathComponent(sceneName,
                                                                    isDirectory: false)
        return realityFileSceneURL
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, ARSessionDelegate {

        private static let logger = Logger(
            subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!,
            category: String(describing: Coordinator.self)
        )

        weak var view: ARView?

        func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
            guard let view = self.view else { return }

            debugPrint("Anchors added to the scene: ", anchors)

            anchors.compactMap { $0 as? ARObjectAnchor }.forEach { anchor in
                debugPrint("Object anchor added")

                // 3: Load .reality file and manually create an AnchorEntity bound to the object
                // anchor that has just been detected. This way, the scene appears.
                let realityFileSceneURL = RealityKitView.createRealityURL(filename: "ImpactHub_Sign", sceneName: "Scene")
                if let realityFileSceneURL {
                    do {
                        let anchorEntity = try Entity.loadAnchor(contentsOf: realityFileSceneURL)

                        anchorEntity.children.forEach { childEntity in
                            let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(anchor: anchor)
                            anchorEntity.addChild(childEntity)
                            view.scene.addAnchor(anchorEntity)
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}



It seems that the problem is indeed that no matter which AnchorEntities are attached to the scene, if the current ARWorldTrackingConfiguration does not contain anything they can anchor to, they simply do not display.
If I try the same with a Reality Composer scene anchored to a horizontal surface, as soon as I set
config.planeDetection = .horizontal

the code part marked with //1. makes the scene display.
This is somewhat counterintuitive, unless there is an API method somewhere that both imports the AnchorEntity and sets up the ARWorldTrackingConfiguration accordingly. This should be perfectly possible, since AnchorEntities themselves contain all the information needed for correctly setting up the ARWorldTrackingConfiguration:
In the following somewhat verbose code, I am doing just that. Namely:

Parsing out the associated enum values of the target property of the root AnchorEntity of the imported scene's anchor, which tell me where the .arobject file (that my scene is anchored to) is located inside the .reality file

Making a copy of the .reality file with a .zip extension outside the app bundle (the ZIP library I am using , https://github.com/marmelroy/Zip, fails otherwise)

Unzipping the .reality file into a temporary folder

Loading an ARReferenceObject from the extracted .arobject file and adding it to ARWorldTrackingConfiguration
  let realityFileSceneURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Watch", withExtension: "reality")
  if let realityFileSceneURL {
      do {
          let anchorEntity = try Entity.loadAnchor(contentsOf: realityFileSceneURL)
          view.scene.addAnchor(anchorEntity)
          if let target = anchorEntity.anchor?.anchoring.target {
              switch(target) {
              case .camera:
                  break
              case .world(transform: let transform):
                  break
              case .anchor(identifier: let identifier):
                  break
              case .plane(_, classification: let classification, minimumBounds: let minimumBounds):
                  break
              case .image(group: let group, name: let name):
                  break
              case .object(group: let group, name: let name):

                  let realityFileUrl = Self.createRealityURL(filename: "Watch")

                  if let realityFileUrl {

                      let realityFileZipUrl = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Watch.zip")

                      try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: realityFileUrl, to: realityFileZipUrl)

                      let unzipFolder = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("arobject")
                      try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: unzipFolder, withIntermediateDirectories: true)

                      debugPrint(realityFileZipUrl)
                      debugPrint(unzipFolder)

                      try Zip.unzipFile(realityFileZipUrl, destination: unzipFolder, overwrite: true, password: nil)

                      let objectUrl = unzipFolder.appendingPathComponent(name)

                      let object = try ARReferenceObject(archiveURL: objectUrl)
                      config.detectionObjects.insert(object)
                      print("Object inserted")
                  }
              case .face:
                  break
              case .body:
                  break
              @unknown default:
                  break
              }
          }
      } catch {
          debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
      }
  }



I have formulated this as a reply due to its length, but I am still curious whether there is any easier way to do this (especially whether there is a method that loads the Reality Composer scene and sets up the ARWorldTrackingConfiguration in one step)
